# $.goMap plugin - Get markers function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am having trouble with the goMap plugin for jquery. I want to obtain all the markers on my map, however, when calling the `getMarkers()` function, it returns an empty array.

I am guessing it has something to do with scopes?

I add the markers by querying the database with an ajax call.

```
$("#canvas").goMap({
    latitude: 44.230065,
    longitude: -76.50000,
    zoom: 14,
    maptype: 'ROADMAP'
});

load_markers();

function load_markers(query_url) {
    if (query_url == undefined) {
        query_url = '/posts/get_markers';
    }

    $.getJSON(query_url, function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(pair) {
            var id = data[pair]['posts']['id'];
            $.goMap.createMarker({
                latitude: data[pair]['posts']['lat'],
                longitude: data[pair]['posts']['lng'],
                draggable: false,
                id: id,
                html: {
                    ajax: "posts/ajax_show/"+id,
                    content: 'loading...',
                    popup: false
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

console.log(($.goMap.getMarkers()));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print it in the success handler of the getJSON call, otherwise you don´t know if you got the data yet. More a timing issue than scope if im correct.

```
$.getJSON(query_url, function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(pair) {
            var id = data[pair]['posts']['id'];
            $.goMap.createMarker({
                latitude: data[pair]['posts']['lat'],
                longitude: data[pair]['posts']['lng'],
                draggable: false,
                id: id,
                html: {
                    ajax: "posts/ajax_show/"+id,
                    content: 'loading...',
                    popup: false
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(($.goMap.getMarkers()));
    });
```